# Why do Python findall() and finditer() return empty matches on unanchored .* searches?

Tags: python, regex

The Python docs for `findall()` and `finditer()` state that:

> Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the
>   beginning of another match

This can be demonstrated as follows:

```
In [20]: [m.span() for m in re.finditer('.*', 'test')]
Out[20]: [(0, 4), (4, 4)]
```

Can anyone tell me though, why this pattern returns an empty match in the first place? Shouldn't `.*` consume the entire string and return a single match? And further, why is there no empty match at the end if I anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string? e.g.

```
In [22]: [m.span() for m in re.finditer('^.*', 'test')]
Out[22]: [(0, 4)]
```

Comment: How could an start-anchored pattern *ever* match something at the end?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. `.*` is *zero or more*, so once the four characters are consumed, the zero-length empty string at the end (which doesn't touch the start of any match) still remains; and
2. The empty string at the end *doesn't match the pattern* - it doesn't start at the start of the string.

Comment: Exactly, try this with `.+`

Comment: Aha! It all seems so obvious now. Thanks very much!

Comment: You can even use this behaviour for non-greedy matches to add empty strings before and after characters, e.g.: `re.findall(r".*?", "foo")` would result in `['', 'f', '', 'o', '', 'o', '']`. I don't know what it's for, but it's a nice one-liner. :)